# Integral with respect to e

Tags: integration

I am stuck trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{3}\frac{1}{3}e^{3t-2}dt$$

I understand that I can take out $\frac{1}{3}$ of the integral, and that the integral of $e^{3t-2}$ is $\frac{1}{3t-2}e^{3t-2}$

However, when I insert the boundaries, I always receive $\frac{1}{7}e^7+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2}$ which yields $\frac{1}{21}e^7+\frac{1}{6}e^{-2}$ when multiplied with $\frac{1}{3}$.

In the solution book, however, it is said to be $\frac{1}{9}(e^7-e^{-2})$.

Does somebody see where my mistake is and know how to get to the correct solution?

Comment: You should just divide by $3$, not by $3t-2$!

Comment: You have the integral wrong, use the u substitution $u=3t-2$ to transform your integral

Comment: "*and the integral of $e^{3t-2}$ is...*"  Are you sure about that?  Maybe it would help to recognize $e^{3t-2}=e^{-2} \cdot (e^3)^t$ noting that $e^{-2}$ is a constant just like $\frac{1}{3}$ is

Comment: By the chain rule $$
\left( {\frac{1}{3}e^{3t - 2} } \right)^\prime   = \frac{1}{3}(3t - 2)'e^{3t - 2}  = e^{3t - 2} .
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a\neq 0$ we have

$$\int e^{at}dt=\frac{1}{a}e^{at}+C$$

Thus we have

$$\int \frac{1}{3} e^{3t-2}dt=\frac{1}{3}\int e^{3t}e^{-2}dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}e^{-2}\int e^{3t}dt=\frac{1}{3}e^{-2}\left[\frac{1}{3}e^{3t}\right]+C=\frac{1}{9}e^{3t-2}+C$$

Answer (score 2):

We have,
$\displaystyle\mathsf{\int^{3}_{0}\,\dfrac{1}{3}\,e^{3t-2}\,dt}$
$\mathtt{Put\,\,\,3t-2=u}$
$\mathtt{\implies\,3\,dt=du}$
$\mathtt{\implies\,dt=\dfrac{du}{3}}$
So, changing limits:
$t=0\,\implies\,u=-2$
$t=3\,\implies\,u=7$
$\displaystyle\mathsf{=\int^{7}_{-2}\,\dfrac{1}{3}\,e^{u}\,\dfrac{du}{3}}$
$\displaystyle\mathsf{=\int^{7}_{-2}\,\dfrac{1}{9}\,e^{u}\,du}$
$\displaystyle\mathsf{=\dfrac{1}{9}\,\int^{7}_{-2}\,e^{u}\,du}$
$\displaystyle\mathsf{=\dfrac{1}{9}\,\left[e^{u}\right]^{7}_{-2}}$
$\displaystyle\mathsf{=\dfrac{1}{9}\,\left[e^{7}-e^{-2}\right]}$
As desired!

Comment: It is a nice idea, but why use \mathtt?

Comment: And \mathsf...?

Comment: It's just a style of writing.. Nothing else